# Перестал собираться проект после перехода Hilt с 2.28 на 2.32

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger

При обнвлении Hilt с версии 2.28 до 2.32 перестал собираться проект.

Вносил изменения только во ViewModel @ViewModelInject на @Inject и добавил @HiltViewModel.

Модуль, в котором собираю зависимости

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object ActivityModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesFirebaseUser(
        firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    ): FirebaseUser {
        return firebaseAuth.currentUser!!
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesFirebaseDatabase(): FirebaseDatabase {
        return Firebase
            .database
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth {
        return Firebase.auth
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesFirebaseDatabaseUserRoot(
        firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase,
        firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    ): DatabaseReference {
        return firebaseDatabase
            .reference
            .child("USERS")
            .child(firebaseUser.uid)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesFirebaseAnalytics(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): FirebaseAnalytics {
        return FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesScopeStore(
        firebaseDatabaseUserRoot: DatabaseReference
    ): ScopeStore {
        return ScopeStore(
            firebaseDatabaseUserRoot
        )
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesSettingsStore(
        firebaseDatabaseUserRoot: DatabaseReference
    ): SettingsStore {
        return SettingsStore(
            firebaseDatabaseUserRoot
        )
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesTemplateStore(
        firebaseDatabaseUserRoot: DatabaseReference
    ): TemplateStore {
        return TemplateStore(
            firebaseDatabaseUserRoot
        )
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesVariableStore(
        firebaseDatabaseUserRoot: DatabaseReference
    ): VariableStore {
        return VariableStore(
            firebaseDatabaseUserRoot
        )
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesServiceCreator(): ServiceCreator {
        return ServiceCreator()
    }
}
```

Конструктор объекта, в который прокидывается DatabaseReference

```
class ScopeStore
@Inject
constructor(
    private val firebaseDatabaseUserRoot: DatabaseReference
)
```

Лог:

```
/home/nikita/StudioProjects/Wesolient/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/vastausf/wesolient/Wesolient_HiltComponents.java:152: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements Wesolient_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference is injected at
          com.vastausf.wesolient.model.store.VariableStore(firebaseDatabaseUserRoot)
      com.vastausf.wesolient.model.store.VariableStore is injected at
          com.vastausf.wesolient.presentation.ui.dialog.createVariable.CreateVariableViewModel(…, variableStore)
      com.vastausf.wesolient.presentation.ui.dialog.createVariable.CreateVariableViewModel is injected at
          com.vastausf.wesolient.presentation.ui.dialog.createVariable.CreateVariableViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.vastausf.wesolient.Wesolient_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.vastausf.wesolient.Wesolient_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.vastausf.wesolient.Wesolient_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
  It is also requested at:
      com.vastausf.wesolient.model.store.ScopeStore(firebaseDatabaseUserRoot)
      com.vastausf.wesolient.model.store.SettingsStore(firebaseDatabaseUserRoot)
      com.vastausf.wesolient.model.store.TemplateStore(firebaseDatabaseUserRoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
Заменить скоуп модуля ActivityComponent на ViewModelComponent